# Copy Link CSS to Non-Link Button

Tags: javascript, c#, css

I'm working on a site where most of its content is generated automatically, and I'm simply creating extensions for it. One extension I'm working on is creating a button.

The buttons on the site have two distinct styles, their regular button css , and their a.button css, as they're link buttons. The buttons are created server-side through asp.net.

I'm able to create the button via Javascript that's inserted into the HTML via a C# StringBuilder, and I can copy the regular css button class through the JS as well with the following command:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(@"<script type=""text/javascript"">");
sb.AppendLine(@"orderInfoTbl.innerHTML = ""<input type='button' id='sameAsShippingButton' onclick='SameAs()' value='Same As Shipping' name='btnSameAsShipping'>"" + orderInfoTbl.innerHTML;");
sb.AppendLine(@"var foo = document.getElementById(""divOfButton""); ");
sb.AppendLine(@"document.getElementById(""sameAsShippingButton"").style.cssText = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(foo, """").cssText");
sb.AppendLine("</script>");
```

My problem is that I can't copy the a.divOfButton css to add to the button to make it match. Is there some Javascript, or another way to steal a whole css id or class and copy it.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I've added your code and it added the class to the actual HTML, so it did indeed do that. But the styles weren't showing up.

Comment: hmm if you inspect the element the class is there?what method did you use? javascript or jquery?

Comment: I used jQuery. The class was added. I think the issue is that it's a server side creation of the button. I've tried adding "runat='server'" to the button. Still nothing.

Comment: hmm well 9Deuce i think you should make another question about this issue, since this question its just about adding the class to a dynamic element

Comment: Good Idea. I will still vote your's the answer since it actually did answer my question. It added the class to an object. Thank you so much Ethaan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try with `addClass()`?

**jQUery**

```
$("#divOfButton").addClass("a.divOfButton");
```

**Javascript**

```
var buttonDynamic = document.getElementById("divOfButton");
buttonDynamic.className = buttonDynamic.className + " a.divOfButton";
```